# How to append a subdirectory to a pathname in Common Lisp

Tags: path, common-lisp, sbcl

I'm having some trouble with path manipulation in Common Lisp (using SBCL). I'm trying to append a subdirectory name to an absolute pathname that I have.

Example: I am running my repl in directory #P"/home/me/somedir" and I have "otherdir" as a variable and what I want is #P"/home/me/somedir/otherdir"

Essentially, I'm trying to translate how I'd do this in Python into Common Lisp: `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "otherdir")`

I've tried `(merge-pathnames (sb-posix:getcwd) "otherdir/")` but I just get the cwd back. If I try `(merge-pathnames "otherdir/" (sb-posix:getcwd))` I instead get otherdir/ prepended before the last directory: #P"/home/me/otherdir/somedir"

I've also tried using `(make-pathname :directory '(:relative "otherdir") :defaults (sb-posix:getcwd))` but I instead get #P"otherdir/somedir".

Does anyone know how to build up a path programmatically in Common Lisp?

Comment: I can't test currently but I suspect strongly the answer is a function wrapped around `(make pathname :directory (append (pathname-directory d) (list my-directory)) :defaults d)` which is ugly but should work.  You need to handle the edge cases for what `pathname-directory` can return.  Merging directories is unfortunately ugly in CL unless I forget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, path handling mysteries… you were nearly there with `merge-pathnames`, but the second argument must have a trailing `/`:

```lisp
(sb-posix:getcwd)
"/home/vince/projets"
```

=> no trailing `/`, so accordingly we get 2 unexpected results when using `otherdir/` (trailing slash) or `otherdir`:

```lisp
(merge-pathnames "otherdir/" (sb-posix:getcwd))
#P"/home/vince/otherdir/projets"
;;                      ^^

(merge-pathnames "otherdir" (sb-posix:getcwd))
#P"/home/vince/otherdir"  ;; no "projets"
```

Let's use a trailing `/` on the right:

```lisp
(merge-pathnames "otherdir" "/home/vince/projets/")
#P"/home/vince/projets/otherdir"  ;; <= expected
```

So is there a more "correct" `cwd`? As often, the solution is given by [UIOP](https://asdf.common-lisp.dev/uiop.html#UIOP_002fOS) (shipped in ASDF, so always available).

TBH I didn't know it before, but I looked it up:

```lisp
(apropos "cwd")
:GETCWD (bound)
OSICAT::CWD
OSICAT-POSIX::%GETCWD (fbound)
OSICAT-POSIX:GETCWD (fbound)
SB-POSIX:GETCWD (fbound)
SB-UNIX:POSIX-GETCWD (fbound)
SB-UNIX:POSIX-GETCWD/ (fbound)
SB-X86-64-ASM::CWD (fbound)
SB-X86-64-ASM::CWDE (fbound)
UIOP/FILESYSTEM::CWD
UIOP/OS:GETCWD (fbound)
```

(YMMV)

So:

```lisp
(UIOP/OS:GETCWD)
#P"/home/vince/projets/"
;;                    ^ yes!
```

and so,

### The solution

```lisp
(merge-pathnames "otherdir" (UIOP/OS:GETCWD))
#P"/home/vince/projets/otherdir"
```

---

UIOP is a portable library. What's the implementation for SBCL? Looking at the source (`M-.`):

```lisp
(sb-ext:parse-native-namestring (sb-unix:posix-getcwd/))
```

Comment: @David: `getcwd` is exported in uiop, we can use `(uiop:getcwd)` instead of `uiop/os:getcwd`

Answer (score 3):

```
>(merge-pathnames "otherdir" #P"/home/me/somedir/")
#P"/home/me/somedir/otherdir"
```

Comment: This is almost certainly making a pathname whose name is `"otherdir"` not one whose directory is `(:absolute ... "otherdir")`.

Comment: To note: with a trailing `/` on the right.

Answer (score 2):

**Constructing new pathnames from existing ones**

Note: For Common Lisp UNIX directories usually have a slash at the end.

The function `PATHNAME` parses a filename string and returns a pathname object.

Using SBCL on a Mac:

```
CL-USER> (pathname "/Users/foo/bar/")
#P"/Users/foo/bar/"

CL-USER> (merge-pathnames "baz/" *)
#P"/Users/foo/bar/baz/"
```

or

```
CL-USER> (let ((p (pathname "/Users/foo/bar/")))
           (make-pathname :defaults p
                          :directory (append (pathname-directory p)
                                             (list "baz"))))
#P"/Users/foo/bar/baz/"
```

**UNIX Pathnames as Lisp objects**

A pathname is a structured object, which also has a *directory* component. Other components are: *device*, *host*, *name*, *type*, version. An absolute directory component of a pathname object looks like this:

```
CL-USER > (pathname-directory (pathname "/Users/foo/bar/"))
(:ABSOLUTE "Users" "foo" "bar")
```

It's a list beginning with the keyword `:absolute`, followed by the directory names as strings.

If we omit the trailing slash, then the `PATHNAME` function will parse the filename differently: the last component will be the name:

```
CL-USER > (pathname-directory (pathname "/Users/foo/bar"))
(:ABSOLUTE "Users" "foo")

CL-USER > (pathname-name (pathname "/Users/foo/bar"))
"bar"
```

Comment: I do not understand what the "*" does in the line `(merge-pathnames "baz/" *)`

Comment: @Vinn  The Variable `*` returns the prior REPL result.